# Conversion between v8::value to date

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8, node.js-nan

I am writing C++ addon on v8 using nan. One of the arguments to constructor is of Date type. IsDate returns true, but I don't know how to convert it to C++ Date object to get Year, Month and Day and etc..

```
void NodeObject::New(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info) {
    if(info[0]->IsDate()) {
        //convert and get year, month and day
        boost::gregorian::date d(2016 , 1 ,1);
        double price = getPrice(date);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your helping!

Comment: What have you written that attempted to do that conversion?  Please provide some code in place of your comment.  How is this code not working as expected?

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler I've added an example. Basically, I need to call a function that takes boost date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast a v8 Value to a Date object with the [v8::Date::Cast](http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1Date.html) function.

From there you can extract the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (1st January 1970) with the `NumberValue` function.

Then convert this number to a [std::time_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t) object by casting the number of seconds `static_cast<time_t>(millisSinceEpoch/1000)`

From the `time_t` get a [struct *tm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) with the [localtime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/) function.

Then finally extracting the day/month/year values:

```
void NodeObject::New(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info) {
  if(info[0]->IsDate()) {
    double millisSinceEpoch = v8::Date::Cast(*info[0])->NumberValue(); 
    std::time_t t = static_cast<time_t>(millisSinceEpoch/1000);

    struct tm* ltime = localtime(&t);
    int year = ltime->tm_year + 1900;
    int month = ltime->tm_mon + 1;
    int day = ltime->tm_mday;

    boost::gregorian::date d(year, month, day);  
    double price = getPrice(date);         
  }
}
```